# Метод в Java как метод str() / int() / bool () в Python

Tags: java, python

В общем я выучил Python, в нем можно просто написать

```
if *допустим просто строка*:
    *Что произойдет если строка не пустая*
```

Например:

```
a = 'Hellow world!'
if a:
    print('Строка вернула True')
```

Так вот. А в яве (я так называю Java) так нильзя, выдает ошибку компиляции.

Какой метод можно использовать в яве чтоб метод возбращал `true` если строка / массив не пустой, иначе `false`?

Также какие есть методы в яве как `str()` / `int()` для перевода в строку / число в Python?

Comment: Про `String` в Java можете почитать [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html)

Answer (score 5):

> Какой метод можно использовать в яве чтоб метод возращал true если строка пустая

```
str.isEmpty();
```

> массив не пустой

```
int[] a = {};
if (a.length == 0)
```

> Также какие есть методы в яве как str() / int() для перевода в строку \ число?

```
int val = 123;
String str String.valueOf(val);
val = Integer.valueOf(str);
str = Integer.toString(val);
val = Integer.parseInt(str);
```